# MDX to add script tag to page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently building some pages that include some animations (Tumult Hype) the usual way to embed the animation is via a div like this:

```
<div id="venafiintegrations_hype_container" class="HYPE_document" style="margin:auto;position:relative;width:1500px;height:800px;overflow:hidden;">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Venafi-Integrations.hyperesources/venafiintegrations_hype_generated_script.js?55179"></script>
    </div>
```

However, if I drop this into the page it seems to break the MDX parser. Is there way to create an MDX component that can create the div and script tags ?

Comment: got an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a react custom hook that loads the script.

From https://usehooks-typescript.com/react-hook/use-script

useScript()
Dynamically load an external script in one line with this React hook. This can be useful to integrate a third party library like Google Analytics or Stripe.

This avoids loading this script in the   on all your pages if it is not necessary.

The Hook

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
export type Status = 'idle' | 'loading' | 'ready' | 'error'
export type ScriptElt = HTMLScriptElement | null
function useScript(src: string): Status {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<Status>(src ? 'loading' : 'idle')
  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (!src) {
        setStatus('idle')
        return
      }
      // Fetch existing script element by src
      // It may have been added by another instance of this hook
      let script: ScriptElt = document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`)
      if (!script) {
        // Create script
        script = document.createElement('script')
        script.src = src
        script.async = true
        script.setAttribute('data-status', 'loading')
        // Add script to document body
        document.body.appendChild(script)
        // Store status in attribute on script
        // This can be read by other instances of this hook
        const setAttributeFromEvent = (event: Event) => {
          script?.setAttribute(
            'data-status',
            event.type === 'load' ? 'ready' : 'error',
          )
        }
        script.addEventListener('load', setAttributeFromEvent)
        script.addEventListener('error', setAttributeFromEvent)
      } else {
        // Grab existing script status from attribute and set to state.
        setStatus(script.getAttribute('data-status') as Status)
      }
      // Script event handler to update status in state
      // Note: Even if the script already exists we still need to add
      // event handlers to update the state for *this* hook instance.
      const setStateFromEvent = (event: Event) => {
        setStatus(event.type === 'load' ? 'ready' : 'error')
      }
      // Add event listeners
      script.addEventListener('load', setStateFromEvent)
      script.addEventListener('error', setStateFromEvent)
      // Remove event listeners on cleanup
      return () => {
        if (script) {
          script.removeEventListener('load', setStateFromEvent)
          script.removeEventListener('error', setStateFromEvent)
        }
      }
    },
    [src], // Only re-run effect if script src changes
  )
  return status
}
export default useScript
```

Usage

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import useScript from './useScript'
// it's an example, use your types instead
declare const jQuery: any
export default function Component() {
  // Load the script asynchronously
  const status = useScript(`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js`)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
      // jQuery is loaded => print the version
      alert(jQuery.fn.jquery)
    }
  }, [status])
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`Current status: ${status}`}</p>
      {status === 'ready' && <p>You can use the script here.</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this